# Views goes to wrong place when using ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am practicing in constraint layout but my problem is when I use constraint layout and adjust all views in my layout it appears to be in a wrong place when run the android emulator how can I fix it or how i ensure that my layout will appears as it in the emulator
**here's the activitymain.xml**

```html
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        tools:text="@string/passenger_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textViewPassangerLabel"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtViewPassangerName"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <TextView
        tools:text="@string/passenger_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtViewPassangerName"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="57dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.39" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shape_rectangle_stroke"
        android:id="@+id/rightRectangle"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="99dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shape_rectangle_stroke"
        android:id="@+id/leftRectangle"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="97dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.96" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="97dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="367dp" />

    <TextView
        tools:text="SFO"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="128dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="32dp" />

    <TextView
        tools:text="LAX"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="114dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="315dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="PassangerTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="22dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rightRectangle"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="PassangerT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="179dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="02:10 PM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="00:15"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBad"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="48dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Department"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="246dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="32dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Arrival"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="48dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="02:40PM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGood"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="271dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="27dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="12:40PM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGood"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

    <ImageView
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shape_rectangle_stroke"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="352dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="305dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Terminal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Gate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Seat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    <ImageView
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shape_rectangle_stroke"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="69dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="345dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shape_rectangle_stroke"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="346dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="136dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shape_rectangle_stroke"
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="344dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="256dp" />

    <TextView
        tools:text="@string/terminal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="355dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="67dp" />

    <TextView
        tools:text="@string/gate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="349dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="153dp" />

    <TextView
        tools:text="@string/seat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="350dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="272dp" />

    <ImageView
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/shape_rectangle_stroke"
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="143dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="97dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/barcode"
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_height="87dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="414dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_plane_icon1"
        android:id="@+id/imageView10"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="92dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/rightRectangle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**here's a photo of emulator(left one) and the activitymain.xml(right one)**

[image: the left photo is android emulator and the right is mylayout]

Comment: Your views are not constraint vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take for example these two views:

```
<TextView
    android:text="PassangerTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="22dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rightRectangle"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

<TextView
    android:text="PassangerT"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="179dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp" />
```

Each of them has some attributes like

```
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="179dp"
```

and some attributes like

```
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```

When you're editing the layout in AndroidStudio, those `tools` attributes will help position your views, but they have **no effect at all** when you actually run your app. The only attributes that actually affect your views' positions are the `layout_constraint` attributes.

If you look closely enough, you'll see that the various views just don't have enough constraints for them to all be laid out correctly. You'll have to go through and add the constraints you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

[image]> Try below : (Add your margin as per your requirement)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_pass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="PASSENGER"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_jams_bond"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="MR. JAMES BOND"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/txt_pass"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_pass" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/leftRectangle"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/img_divider"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_jams_bond"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/middleRectangle"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/img_divider"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/leftRectangle"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/rightRectangle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_jams_bond"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_divider"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="#808080"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/leftRectangle"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/leftRectangle"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/rightRectangle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/leftRectangle"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="97dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="144dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rightRectangle"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/img_divider"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_jams_bond"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pass_time"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Passenger Time"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/leftRectangle"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/middleRectangle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/leftRectangle" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_good_time"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="02:10 PM"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/pass_time"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/pass_time"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pass_time" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pass_t"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Passenger Time"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/middleRectangle"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/rightRectangle"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rightRectangle" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_bad_time"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="00:15"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/pass_t"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/pass_t"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pass_t" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_depart"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Department"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/pass_time"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/pass_time"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_good_time" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_depart_time"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="02:40 PM"
    android:textColor="#008000"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/txt_depart"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/txt_depart"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_depart" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_arrival"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Arrival"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/pass_t"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/pass_t"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_bad_time" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_arrival_time"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="12:40 PM"
    android:textColor="#008000"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/txt_arrival"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/txt_arrival"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_arrival" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnr_gate"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/pass_time"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/pass_t"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_depart_time">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Terminal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Gate"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Seat"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnr_2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/lnr_gate"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/lnr_gate"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lnr_gate">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="58B"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="24A"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/lnr_2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/lnr_2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lnr_2"
    />
```